# Exception while creating table in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

While creating table in Azure

```
    public void Create()
    {
        TableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(TableName);
    }
```

i am getting the following exception :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
 <code>OutOfRangeInput</code>
 <message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:df3a853d-5ff6-46ec-908e-99ddf49c104c
Time:2012-08-21T13:41:43.9555920Z</message>
</error>
```

can anyone please explain me the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table name is invalid.  What's the name you are using?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx):

Table names must conform to these rules:

Table names must be unique within an account.

Table names may contain only alphanumeric characters.

Table names cannot begin with a numeric character.

Table names are case-insensitive.

Table names must be from 3 to 63 characters long.

These rules are also described by the regular expression "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,62}$".

Table names preserve the case with which they were created, but are case-insensitive when used.